# Can you have a selective segmentation mask with MediaPipe's Pose solution?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, object-detection, mask, mediapipe

Is there a way to selectively mask pose landmarks in MediaPipe? MediaPipe allows me to apply a segmentation mask to a pose with the `enable_segmentation` parameter, but it gives me the entire body. Is it possible to, for example, segment only the right leg? The left hand?

Pose detection:

[image: Example animated image of MediaPipe detecting body landmarks of a man doing yoga]

Segmentation Mask:

[image: Image of a man dancing. The background is washed out with the help of a MediaPipe pose segmentation mask.]

Comment: https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/pose.html#pose_landmarks Why can't you use the pose points to pick the body parts. For example 26,28,30,32 gives the right leg.

Comment: pose estimation is very much different from instance/semantic segmentation. if the segmentation network wasn't trained for this flexibility, you'll have a task ahead of you.